# Can't use Google App Script to upload an unzipped csv into BigQuery with bigger size data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I use a platform to send a report with CSV/ZIP file to my Gmail automatically, the platform will decide which type to send based on the size. And I build this Google Apps Script to push this file to BigQuery.

I try this on a smaller size zip (zip like few hundred KBs, 25MB when unzipped), and it has no problem. However, when it goes to a bigger size (zip like 3MB, 77MB when unzipped), I got an error message when processing the Job.Load. Wondering if anyone had experience this issue and willing to share some tips. Thanks.

Sorry that the error message showing on my UI is Chinese, so I just skip attaching that to this thread:(

Here's the code:

```
function BQLoad() {
var projectId = 'quantum-feat-211902';
var datasetId = 'DBM_dataset01';
var tableId = 'test';
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; 
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; 
var attachments = message.getAttachments()[0];
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
var messages = firstThread.getMessages();
var job = {
configuration: {
  load: {
    destinationTable: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId,
    },
    skipLeadingRows: 1,
    ignoreUnknownValues: true,
    writeDisposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    sourceFormat: 'CSV',
    fieldDelimiter: ',',
    allowJaggedRows: true,
    encoding: "UTF-8",
    maxBadRecords: 1000,
  },
},
};
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
Logger.log(messages[i].getSubject());
}
Logger.log(attachments.getContentType());
if (attachments.getContentType() === "application/zip") {
var data = Utilities.unzip(attachments)[0];
}
else {
var data = attachments;
}
job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
Logger.log('Load job started. Check on the status of it here: ' +
  'https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/%s', projectId);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to translate the error message into English?  It might help a lot to know what the specific error is.  As an educated guess, some times problems like this happen when there are time limits set on the servers running the code, or size limits on the data they are allowed to handle.  A big file might cause the script to run too long.

Comment: Thank you Brian:) the error message is something about "Can't find any content" on line 39: job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data); don't know if it has anything to do with the data

Comment: @Adventurous Leo - does this happen for big ZIP files only and for all big ZIP or some? Can you try with a big CSV file so that we could understand where the problem arises? I saw a [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) about uploading from Drive, but I guess that is not an option for you?

Comment: I think I just realized why this happened. It's my quota, I have only 50MB per URI, I'll just reduce the size and do a batch upload. Still thanks to you two for giving me directions.

Comment: @Adventurous Leo can you post this as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Answer (score 1):

Posting answer from @Adventurous Leo for visibility

> I think I just realized why this happened. It's my quota, I have only
>   50MB per URI, I'll just reduce the size and do a batch upload. Still
>   thanks to you two for giving me directions